# I edit code of my java web-app but it remains the same. Netbeans 20, Tomcat 10.1

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am making my java web-app. I edit data of my app, for example, change pictures, but when i run it using tomcat there are no changes. In my project's settings option "Compile on Save" is activated. What's the problem?